# Page navigation using routing

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I am trying to navigate to a new jsp page on click of a link . I am using routing for this .

**home.jsp**

I am having below div outside the ng-view directive .If I am putting this inside ng-view ,Page is not working properly .I dont know if it should be inside or outside .

```
<div>
            <h4> <a href ="#/Mix.web" data-ng-click="getMixData()" target="_self">Overall Mix
            </a></h4>
            </div>
```

**Mix.jsp**

I have not put it inside ng-view .Again If I am enclosing it inside ng-view ,the page is not loading .

**Controller js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);



app.config(function($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider

        .when('/home.web', {

            templateUrl : 'Views/Home.jsp',

            controller  : 'MyController'

        })

        .when('/Mix.web', {

                      templateUrl : 'Views/Mix.jsp',

                    controller  : 'MyController'

               });





});
```

Few things I have debugged . 
Onclick of the link , controller function is getting called and subsequent java spring controller is sending data successfully as well .

I am not able to figure out if this is the correct way to implement routing . What am I doing wrong here .